# CGRectDivide with NULL pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, null, core-graphics

In the following code, is it possible to get rid of `nothing` variable?

```
CGRect startTableViewFrame;
CGRect nothing;
CGRectDivide(tableViewFrame,
             &nothing,
             &startTableViewFrame,
             searchBarHeight - contentOffset,
             CGRectMinYEdge);
```

`NULL` doesn't seem to work. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could do this

```
CGRectDivide(tableViewFrame,
             &(CGRect){},
             &startTableViewFrame,
             searchBarHeight - contentOffset,
             CGRectMinYEdge);
```

or even this:

```
MyCGRectDivide( CGRect r, CGRect * slice, CGRect * remainder, CGFloat d, CGRectEdge edge )
{
    slice = slice ? slice : &(CGRect){} ;
    remainder = remainder ? remainder : &(CGRect){} ;

    CGRectDivide( r, slice, remainder, d, edge ) ;
}
```